# My aqua/prius c came without a auto side mirror closing/opening option when locking/unlocking the car. How to install that option?

Tags: toyota, hybrid, prius

I have a 2012 aqua G model. The newer versions have the auto side mirror closing/opening option when locking/unlocking the car. How can I install this in my car?
Do I need a software update or a new mechanical part or both?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the mirrors look physically the same?

Comment: Yes, physically the same.

Comment: If they will physically fit, then I would try and get hold of a wiring diagram for both cars.  If you have some understanding of wiring it wouldn't be difficult to wire them up if it is just the lock/unlock action that controls them.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on whether your year of car supported the option or not. If it never had the option then you might as well buy the newer model. This is because retrofitting an option such as this would be extremely expensive, requiring wiring and computers and all kinds of things.

If your year car had the option and just your trim line didn't offer it then it may be possible, but still not guaranteed. The best case scenario, Toyota offers a set of mirrors with the necessary motors and the wiring is already there. Worst case scenario, the cars are too diffident between the trim lines of the same year and then see above.

Best bet call the parts department of your local Toyota dealer.